# How to calculate the partial derivative function at any general point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[screenshot with transcription below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tF43.png)

> Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
> $$
> f(x, y)=\left(1-\cos \frac{x^{2}}{y}\right) \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}
> $$
> for $y \neq 0$ and $f(x, 0)=0$. (The square root is chosen to be non-negative).

$f_x$ and $ f_y $ exists at origin and are equal to $0$. How do i calculate the partial derivative function (e.g. $f_x$) at any general point . Since , this is a discrete function , i will not like to differentiate it partially w.r.t. x and would like to do by standard definition .Please use the neighbourhood if you can ,since it makes things clear.

Also,Is this differentiable at $(0,0)$ ?

Please avoid using the directional derivative definition of calculating the limit of the definition. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What makes you think this is a "discrete function"?  It is clearly defined on the usual $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the range is easily shown to be not discrete.

Comment: Since there is a point where the function is alternatively defined , so i thought in that respect. Can i say this -> if i am calculating say $f_x$ at any other point than $(0,0)$ ,i can always find a neighbourhood where the given function is always defined smoothly and therefore take partial derivative of the function w.r.t $x$.

Comment: Hi there, please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax. This helps users with slow connections, poor eyesight, or maybe imgur is blocked in their workplace. You can get started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I've done it for you this time, but please do it yourself in the future

Comment: By ”discrete“ function, you probably mean "piecewise-defined function". And the only place where the derivative rules may not hold is when $y=0$: $f$ is smooth everywhere else, so you can differentiate the formula freely

Comment: @CalvinKhor Just to be specific here, in general , if i want to differentiate a function $f$ directly say at a general point $(a,b)$ , can i do that if i can find a neighbourhood around $(a,b)$ , where $f$ is smooth.?

Comment: yes, that is precisely right @HarshVardhanSingh

Comment: One sufficient condition for differentiability at $(a,b)$ is that 'one of the partial derivative must exist at $(a,b)$ and the other must be continuous at $(a,b)$' .Here , $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist at $(0,0)$ and are equal to $0$ . However , i calculated that neither of them is continuous at $(0,0)$. So ,can i conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ ?